# My reducer returns undefined as if it wasn't added into combineReducers, but it is

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Everything seems to be perfectly ok, I've been debugging this for some time and I can't seem to understand where's the problem

reducers/index.js

```
// @flow
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import blocks from "./blocks";
import users from "./users";
import add from "./add";
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    blocks,
    users,
    add
});
export default rootReducer;
```

reducers/add.js

```
// @flow
import AnyAction from "redux";
import * as ActionTypes from "./../constants";

const initialState = {
    number: 0
};

export default function Add(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.ADD:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                number: number + 1
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

connect function

```
const { navigation, blocks, dispatch, number } = this.props;
.
.
.
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    blocks: state.blocks,
    number: state.number
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BlockList);
```

Comment: `number: number + 1` seems like it's adding  `1` to `undefined`, can you try `number: state.number + 1` ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. However, that bug was completely unrelated to my problem.

Comment: There is no number value assigned to your combineReducer function so state.number would not return anything

Comment: When is this actually occurring? When the store builds or when the reducer is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After combining your reducers, you need to access your reducer's states in your mapStateToProps by using the combined reducer name. Instead of:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   blocks: state.blocks,
   number: state.number
});
```

Have this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  blocks: state.blocks,
  number: state.add.number
});
```

Now, with `state.add.number`, you can access the number state inside your add.js reducer.

I tried to recreate your problem here:

[image: Edit loving-tharp-fe3ti]

Comment: Thanks, this works, but how come I have to add ".add", but don't have to add ".blocks"?

Comment: Keep in mind that when you have combinedReducers, you get the reducer full state by using state.{reducerName}, so for blocks, you're getting the full state object with `blocks: state.blocks`, but since in the reducer add you're just interested in the `number`, then you can get the whole add state by doing `state.add`, then the specific variable inside the state you need, which is `state.add.number`. If you want a specific variable inside the blocks reducer object state, then you would need to define it with `randomVariable: state.blocks.randomVariable`.